# How can I automate page load time testing?

Tags: lightning-web-components, performance

I'm trying to get metrics for page load times. I'd like to load the page many times, say 100 times, and get the average time it took to load the page, from a virtual Cmd-R to the page remaining stable because the data has loaded. The page contains datatable that loads 50 records using SOQL on Apex.

I'm using `?eptVisible=1` to get what Salesforce calls "Experienced Page Time," but this doesn't seem to actually record the time to load the page, but perhaps the time to load my web components. It doesn't seem to start counting until a couple of seconds into page load.

Is there a tool, preferably perhaps a Chrome extension, that can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Chrome headless browser](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) with [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) (or other alternatives) to create a script and measure the values for each load. Or you could use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). There are ways to handle doing this if you do a bit of research. Hopefully I've given you a few keywords to help you find what you're looking for.